# Why is my 5K potentiometer sparking during regulation of LED bulb?

Tags: led, potentiometer

There are two potentiometers in my DC circuit analysis. When I turn on the wall switch, which is connected to the 220V transformer which is in turn connected to the circuit, one of the potentiometers is sparking (as seen in the picture), when it is being regulated to increase/decrease light intensity of the LED. What could be the reason for this?

And should I replace the potentiometer before I solder the components onto a narrow board? Could it be sparking because the circuit is connected to a very high voltage wall power supply, instead of a battery with lower power?

Please help out.

[image]

Comment: Schematic required... And if that transformer and 220V supply aren't being used correctly there is a possible Darwin Award here, so switch off and be careful!

Comment: What are the specifications of the transformer (nominal output voltage). Hopefully it is a step-down.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your transformer is stepping down to a reasonable voltage, here is a guess. When your potentiometer wiper is near the lower end, the resistance seen by the transformer will be very low, and the current will be very high, causing sparks and overheating.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgfSnO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Every potentiometer has a max working voltage. Be sure you are picking the potentiometer with the right voltage ratio.

Comment: Could be that you are drawing too much current through the pot. Laurin Cavender WB4IVG